# "a film without propaganda" grammatical?

Tags: sentence-construction

> This is a film without propaganda, a balanced movie.
>
> This is a war film without propaganda.

"a film without propaganda" grammatical? It doesn't sound quite right, because it implies a movie can contain a propaganda, when the movie should be a propaganda or not. Is it grammatical or not? I am not quite sure to be honest.

Comment: Propaganda is a uncountable noun; we don't say 'a propaganda'.

Comment: Trying to make a war film without making it into propaganda seems to be about as likely as making an anti-war film.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is perfectly grammatical though, as you say, it does not sound natural. When used to describe a film, it is conventional to make a compound noun **propaganda film**, so it would probably sound better as

> it's not a propaganda film.

This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not%20a%20propaganda%20film%2Cfilm%20without%20propaganda&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20a%20propaganda%20film%3B%2Cc0) shows that this is the opinion of others too.